# MANCOVA with categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-testing

By doing an experiment, I would like to analyze the effect of 3 categorical independent variables (with 2 levels each) on three constructs measured with ordinal variables. I also have 2 covariates (with ordinal variables). Among the findings, I expect correlations among the three constructs. Can I use MANCOVA to run such analysis with this type of data? In case it is possible, what could be the main issue(s)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You seem to be asking for a solution without providing any examples of your own attempts.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I have not tried anything so far. In fact, I am trying to understand what statistical test could fit best, before trying out many of them. Is this an incorrect approach?

Comment: I understand. I recommend you use https://datascience.stackexchange.com for this question.